# Ebizmart Mailchimp Interest Group Issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, mailchimp, mail

I'm using Magento2 and I installed the module `Ebizmarts_MailChimp` in my local and setup using the MailChimp account.

Everything is working fine except that when I add a group interest on an account that can be updated on the `My Account -> Newsletter`, it saves on the magento side but doesn't sync on the MailChimp side.

May anyone help me?